# Find different values between 2 lists of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, intersection, difference

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [
    {
        "address": "1000",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "2000",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "3000",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "4000",
        "amount": 20
    }
]
```

```
list2 = [
    {
        "account": "1000",
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "account": "2000",
        "balance": 200
    },
    {
        "account": "3000",
        "balance": 300
    }
]
```

I want to search `list2` and see if the value from `list1` key "address" is already present in `list2` as a value tied to "account" key.

If it is not, append both "address" & "amount" to `list2` as "account" & "balance".

Example:

`list1` "address" of 4000 is not in `list2` as `account: 4000`, so I want to add that entire dict to `list2` as:

```
    {
        "account": "4000",
        "balance": 20
    }
```

What I have tried already based on other SO questions:

```
def unique_values_from_list(dict_list):
    all_values = set()
    for dictionary in dict_list:
        all_values.update(dictionary.values())
    return all_values

unique_1 = unique_values_from_list(list1)
unique_2 = unique_values_from_list(list2)

intersection = unique_1.intersection(unique_2)
```

Which gives the values of keys: `address`/`account` that are in both lists of dicts.
But I don't know where to go from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to build a set of `list2` inner dictionaries values (for the "account" key), then loop over list1:

```
keys2 = {d['account'] for d in list2 if 'account' in d}
# {'1000', '2000', '3000'}

out = [{'account': d['address'], 'balance': d['amount']}
       for d in list1
       if (a:=d.get('address', None)) and a not in keys2]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[{'account': '4000', 'balance': 20}]
```

If you rather want to update `list2`:

```
keys2 = {d['account'] for d in list2 if 'account' in d}
# {'1000', '2000', '3000'}

for d in list1:
    if (a:=d.get('address', None)) and a not in keys2:
        list2.append({'account': d['address'], 'balance': d['amount']})

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[{'account': '1000', 'balance': 100},
 {'account': '2000', 'balance': 200},
 {'account': '3000', 'balance': 300},
 {'account': '4000', 'balance': 20}]
```

Comment: @bn_ln that's a good point, thanks! I updated

Answer (score 0):

Another working method would be to convert list1 and list 2 to dicts, and update the first dict with the 2nd:

```
dict1 = {e['address']:e['amount'] for e in list1}
dict2 = {e['account']:e['balance'] for e in list2}
dict1.update(dict2)

# {'1000': 100, '2000': 200, '3000': 300, '4000': 20}
```

Then you can turn dict1 back to a list if you wish (though it's probably easier to use by keeping it as is):

```
list3 = [{'account':key, 'balance':val} for key, val in dict1.items()]

# [{'account': '1000', 'balance': 100},
#  {'account': '2000', 'balance': 200},
#  {'account': '3000', 'balance': 300},
#  {'account': '4000', 'balance': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the values of address in list1 that are not in list2 and append them to the list2.

```
for i in list1:
  if i.get("address") not in list(value['account'] for value in list2):
    list2.append({"account": i.get("address"), "balance": i.get("amount")})
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[{'account': '1000', 'balance': 100}, {'account': '2000', 'balance': 200}, {'account': '3000', 'balance': 300}, {'account': '4000', 'balance': 20}]
```